# What is this object on Noriko's neck at the end of “Godzilla: Minus One?”

Tags: godzilla

At the end of *Godzilla: Minus One* (2023) Noriko is shown with some kind of bruise or something on her neck. What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the film's director, he wanted the end to be bittersweet. She's alive (for now), but she's been left injured in an intentionally ambiguous way.

> "I wanted Shikishima to reunite with Noriko at the end, but I didn't
> want it to be  a "typical happy ending.''
>
> I decided to let Noriko live in that way. As **Godzilla is a symbol of
> war and nuclear weapons, so while she did not die, that doesn't mean
> that only happiness awaits her.**
>
> No I didn't want a happy ending... However, I am at a point where I
> didn't want to have a cruel ending either."
>
> <sub><sup>[Per twitter](https://twitter.com/GormaruIsland/status/1737228979315056873?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1737228979315056873%7Ctwgr%5E98f3544c58f80a986e4ce0df280169f0046fb400%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmovieweb.com%2Fgodzilla-minus-one-director-explains-ending%2F)</sup></sub>

and

> "The Tatari-gami from Princess Mononoke also comes to a village he has
> no connections with, messes it up, and **leaves behind a curse**. That's
> how I felt after making this film. I felt that making a Godzilla movie
> was a divine ritual. The ritual [gathers] the anxieties of the world
> at the time and summons them as a cursed deity which must be
> appeased."
>
> <sub><sup>[GODZILLA MINUS ONE Director Explains How the Film's Ending Can Lead to a Sequel](https://geektyrant.com/news/godzilla-minus-one-director-explains-how-the-films-ending-can-lead-to-a-sequel)</sup></sub>

Minami Hamabe joked in an interview that she may have been infected with a piece of Godzilla.

> “If there is a next series, I might be the one stepping on and crushing people (lol).”
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/14_kaiju/status/1732558679076135394)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

I found this article (link below) on a site named "The Mary Sue", which relates articles and news for numerous categories.

Briefly, the bruise is speculated as either a sign of radiation poisoning from Godzilla's atomic breath, or a sign that Noriko was contaminated in some way by Godzilla itself, and that this contamination may have a role in a possible sequel. The second theory was considered less likely

> “At the hospital, Noriko is seen with what appears to be a black mark on her neck. Despite being so noticeable, no explanation of the mark is given. Hence, many viewers simply assumed it was a sign of radiation poisoning. One of the reasons why she is presumed dead is because she was caught in the blast radius of Godzilla’s atomic breath. With its nuclear breath boasting similarities to a nuclear bomb, the only thing more devastating than the original blast is the radiation released by it. In Japan, one of the long-lasting effects of the atomic bombs was radiation sickness. Many who survived the initial blast later died from radiation exposure, which the United States initially tried to cover up.”

- https://www.themarysue.com/godzilla-minus-one-norikos-neck-explained/